# 403 code when using python request library

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I have gone through most of the posts related to 403 error and tried all of the options. However I am still not able to fix, I keep getting 403 error.

I have tried various combinations of the headers but no luck

**Here is my code :**

```
import requests


headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'referer': 'https://www.whatismyip.com/52.242.97.97/',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get('https://www.whatismyip.com/40.70.224.149/', headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: For now, i just want to get the 200 OK response.
Later I will doing regex and BS4 to get the deatils out of it

Comment: Can someone please assist on how to proceed ?